# Using the LibGdx Music API from within Android applcation

Tags: android, libgdx

I have an android application.
Part of the features of the app is to play ogg files.
I tried using the `MediaPlayer` for this task, but it caused huge slowdown of the app on the first play.
I'm guessing this is because the music file is loaded whole into memory, which leaves less memory for the app.

The question is, is it possible to use only the `Music` API of LibGdx for this task?
Can I use it without all the stuff with the application of LibGdx, since I have my own activities written in pure Android code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i would recommend to take a look into the [Music backend of libgdx](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidMusic.java). There is code for the regular music Api which you can take a look at. Everything there is pure android and i am sure that you can take snippets of it to create your own musik player.

I would recommend to put that into it's own thread so it does not effect your other code. Use a kind of event system to start stop new songs for example.

I dont think, that you can simply integrate a part of libgdx to your project. If you try to take a look at the wiki about [interfaceing with platform code.](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) Create an interface in your android project and create a player in the core project of libgdx. Now just call that interface inside of your android project and it get forwared to the libgdx core "musicplayer".

Comment: I see that LibGDX implementation is also using the MediaPlayer. So I guess this won't solve my slowness problem, since I am also using the MediaPlayer. But I will try spawning a different thread for the music, and will check how it goes.

Comment: regulary you spawn a new thread for stuff like music so i hope and guess it will solve the issue. Yes libgdx uses platform spec code and for android its the mediaplayer for the music